# How can I use the Linux CLI to change keyboard input method?

Tags: linux-mint, input-languages

I'd like to be able to switch between U.S. ASCII and Russian (in Russia) keyboard input.

I would ideally like to be able to do so from a custom launcher on a panel or Cairo-dock.

This is under Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon edition.

Thanks,

Comment: try: setxkbmap ru

Comment: Thanks; could you restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set keyboard layout with:

`setxkbmap ru`